# What's up with the current monthly rep point totals on TeX.SE?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stackexchange

I just took a look at the first page of site's users, listed by within-month rep count:

[image]

While the names seem comfortably familiar, the rep point totals for many of the users seem high -- impressively high, in fact! So high, actually, that they seem off. E.g., how come that @egreg, far and away our most productive contributor, is only in fourth place?

I then calculated the actual month-to-date totals:

```
           shown  actual
        
Werner      5375    1605
ulrike f    3348     775
gonzalo m   3048     978
egreg       2530    2530 *
leandriis   2263     405
bernard     2168     715
moewe       2055     715
david c     1765    1765 *
mico        1647    1647 *
zarko       1583    1583 *
phelype o   1449     125
lockstep    1430     440
```

As you can see, I was able to obtain a "match" between the reported and actual totals for only 4 out of the 12 top-ranked users; the matches are marked with an asterisk.

**Questions**: Is this discrepancy something that should give us cause for concern? And, is this issue specific to TeX.SE, or is this a bug that affects all StackExchange sites?

Comment: Why such a nice ranking give cause for concern???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a scheduled job running each month to reset the counters. It [failed December 1, 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403547/394787), sorry for this. That's why the November values are included, so it's too high.

SE started a network wide recalculation that should fix it after some time.

The [monthly reputation league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/85/month/tex) looks better already.

Comment: Many thanks for these pieces of information. It would appear that the scheduled job that's supposed to compute the monthly totals and then reset the counters failed in 8 out of 12 cases. Hopefully this issue will get fixed soon.